# How to test for an error and specific error message using testthat in R

Tags: r, testthat

I am attempting to write a test that ensures that, given a certain input, a function

1. errors
2. provides a specific error message

I am using `testthat::expect_error()`

### Example

As a very simple, reproducible example suppose we have a multiplication function

```
test_funct <- function(x) { x * 2 }
```

And a very simple test to test that it errors when provided an input of class character:

```
test_that(
  "function errors when it receives a character object", 
  { test_funct("a") %>% expect_error("non-numeric argument to binary operator") } 
  )
```

### The problem

I was expecting this test to pass, since `"a"` is of class character and would indeed produce the error message provided to `expect_error()` (i.e. `"non-numeric argument to binary operator"`).

However, the test does not pass, instead returning:

```
Error: Test failed: 'function errors when it receives a character object'
* non-numeric argument to binary operator
1: test_funct("a") %>% expect_error("non-numeric argument to binary operator")
2: eval(lhs, parent, parent)
3: eval(lhs, parent, parent)
4: test_funct("a")
```

How can I create a test that checks that a function errors and provides a certain error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the pipe operator. It should work, but it throws the error you get. At least with testthat version 2.0.1. If I use the none pipe code like below, the test passes.

```
test_that(
  "function errors when it receives a character object", 
  { expect_error(test_funct("a"), "non-numeric argument to binary operator") } 
)
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I wonder why the pipe operator doesn't work (it works fine for `expect_equal()`)

Comment: I expected it to work. You could open a github ticket because this error has not been reported yet.